# Read and Write to php file

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am looking for a method to write the values of some variable to a PHP file.

Ok let me explain by example:

I have a normal PHP website and want to add WordPress as a blog to it.

I use the same theme as of my WordPress for the other site too, removing the WordPress tags and replacing them with my other application’s tags. So here the Div IDs and Class names remain the same.  Also I share the same CSS & JS files as WordPress.

I want to control the width of my sidebars and some other parameters from the WordPress Theme control panel. The process I think should be…

get value for 'sidebar_a' and say inputs is '150px'
get value for 'main_body' and say inputs is '550px'
get value for 'sidebar_b' and say inputs is '200px'
get value for ‘site_name’ and say the input comes from the WordPress tag
get value for ‘footer ‘and say again the value comes from the WordPress footer.

Now I need a small script which will write these values in a PHP file like:

```
$sidebar_a = '100'

$main_body = '550'

$sidebar_b = '200'

$sitename = ‘XYZ Corporation’

$footer = ‘Copyright XYZ corporation'
```

or better create some database tables in MySQL and write to it.

I would then want to call this file in my application 2 using

Please feel free to suggest, if there is a better way.

**IMPORTANT:** Every time these parameters are changed in WordPress, these values must be updated with the new values.

Kindly help.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Developer_Documentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write data

```
$data = array(
    'sidebar_a' => $sidebar_a,
    'main_body' => $main_body,
    'sidebar_b' => $sidebar_b,
    'sitename' => $sitename,
    'footer' => $footer
);
$data = serialize($data);
file_put_contents('file.txt', $data);
```

Read data

```
$data = file_get_contents('file.txt');
$data = unserialize($data);
extract($data);
```

See `serialize` and `extract`

http://php.net/serialize

http://php.net/extract

Comment: Hey thanks for answering but please don't mind I am a total newbie to programming. Just 2 things: 1. can I include the value also as a variable? For example 'sidebar_a' => $sidebara_width,. and How do I update these values every time I change the width of sidebars. Is this a continuously updating process?

Comment: Yes, I changed the code to demonstrate it.  By update the values, do you mean edit the text file?

Comment: Yes I mean I get the values as  $sidebar_width = $doc->params->get("side-bar-width","180"); and the result must be written to a php file exactly like this $singlebar_width = '200; What will be the exact code for this and aslo that every time the value is updated in the template configurations, this PHP file must get updated.

Comment: Um, are you planning in including the file?  You don't, the second piece of code is what that's for.  Did you look at what `extract()` does?

Answer (score 1):

To store PHP variables in a file (as the topic states) I would store all the configuration values into an array and then use the `serialize()`/`unserialize()` functions and then read/write to a file.

Eg:

```
file_put_contents('myconf.txt', serialize($my_array));
$my_array = unserialize(file_get_contents('myconf.txt'));
```

If you absolutely need to include the created configuration file somewhere else in order to get the configuration (I don't see why, but you possibly could do it), you can instead use something like this:

```
file_put_contents('myconf.php', '$my_array = '. var_export($my_array, TRUE) .';');
```

and then just

```
include 'myconf.php';
```

..then I think you should create some patch to Wordpress core to make it write to this file every time the configuration values are changed.

Or, a better solution IMHO, would be to make the other application read directly from the Wordpress database, in order to avoid possible incoherences and all the problems derived by patching some third-party application code.

Comment: Hey thanks for answering but please don't mind I am a total newbie to programming. I am basically a designer. Can you kindly explain me with a small example or illustration.